# How do I Import imdb dataset using Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror, imdb

I am trying to import imdb dataset from keras on CoLab platform.

and I got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _get_default_graph()
     65     try:
---> 66         return tf.get_default_graph()
     67     except AttributeError:
```

AttributeError: module '`tensorflow`' has no attribute '`get_default_graph`'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _get_default_graph()
     67     except AttributeError:
     68         raise RuntimeError(
---> 69             'It looks like you are trying to use '
     70             'a version of multi-backend Keras that '
     71             'does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend '
```

RuntimeError: It looks like you are trying to use a version of multi-backend Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using `tf.keras`, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14.

The code I am using:

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import keras
from keras.datasets import imdb
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(path="imdb.npz",
                                                  num_words=None,
                                                  skip_top=0,
                                                  maxlen=None,
                                                  seed=113,
                                                  start_char=1,
                                                  oov_char=2,
                                                  index_from=3)
```

Comment: The problem and solution is clear: RuntimeError: It looks like you are trying to use a version of multi-backend Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using tf.keras, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please tell me how to do the suggested solution?

Comment: Use tf.keras, or upgrade Keras to a version that supports TensorFlow 2.0 (like Keras 2.3.1), or downgrade TensorFlow to 1.14/1.15

Answer (score 1):

You can load the IMDB dataset into TensorFlow using below methods.

**1. Using tensorflow.keras.datasets:**

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb 

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(path="imdb.npz",
                                                  num_words=None,
                                                  skip_top=0,
                                                  maxlen=None,
                                                  seed=113,
                                                  start_char=1,
                                                  oov_char=2,
                                                  index_from=3)
```

Which will be having 25000 records each in both `x_train` and `x_test`

**2. Using tensorflow_datasets:**

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load('imdb_reviews', split='train')

for ex in ds.take(4):
  print(ex)
```

Sample data:

```
{'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>, 'text': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b"This was an absolutely terrible movie. Don't be lured in by Christopher Walken or Michael Ironside. Both are great actors, but this must simply be their worst role in history. Even their great acting could not redeem this movie's ridiculous storyline. This movie is an early nineties US propaganda piece. The most pathetic scenes were those when the Columbian rebels were making their cases for revolutions. Maria Conchita Alonso appeared phony, and her pseudo-love affair with Walken was nothing but a pathetic emotional plug in a movie that was devoid of any real meaning. I am disappointed that there are movies like this, ruining actor's like Christopher Walken's good name. I could barely sit through it.">}
{'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>, 'text': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'I have been known to fall asleep during films, but this is usually due to a combination of things including, really tired, being warm and comfortable on the sette and having just eaten a lot. However on this occasion I fell asleep because the film was rubbish. The plot development was constant. Constantly slow and boring. Things seemed to happen, but with no explanation of what was causing them or why. I admit, I may have missed part of the film, but i watched the majority of it and everything just seemed to happen of its own accord without any real concern for anything else. I cant recommend this film at all.'>}
{'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>, 'text': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Mann photographs the Alberta Rocky Mountains in a superb fashion, and Jimmy Stewart and Walter Brennan give enjoyable performances as they always seem to do. <br /><br />But come on Hollywood - a Mountie telling the people of Dawson City, Yukon to elect themselves a marshal (yes a marshal!) and to enforce the law themselves, then gunfighters battling it out on the streets for control of the town? <br /><br />Nothing even remotely resembling that happened on the Canadian side of the border during the Klondike gold rush. Mr. Mann and company appear to have mistaken Dawson City for Deadwood, the Canadian North for the American Wild West.<br /><br />Canadian viewers be prepared for a Reefer Madness type of enjoyable howl with this ludicrous plot, or, to shake your head in disgust.'>}
{'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>, 'text': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'This is the kind of film for a snowy Sunday afternoon when the rest of the world can go ahead with its own business as you descend into a big arm-chair and mellow for a couple of hours. Wonderful performances from Cher and Nicolas Cage (as always) gently row the plot along. There are no rapids to cross, no dangerous waters, just a warm and witty paddle through New York life at its best. A family film in every sense and one that deserves the praise it received.'>}
```

This also will be having the same split as above.

Comment: @Nibras Abo Alzahab If your issue is resolved using the above approach, please accept and upvote the answer.